# Prove that if there exists $f\colon A \rightarrow B$ that is an onto map, then there exists a one-to-one map from $B$ to $ A$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if there exists a map $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ that is onto, then there exists a one-to-one map from $B$ to $A$.

Welcome any guidance for this question.

Comment: Consider the inverse map $f^{-1}\colon B \to \mathcal P(A)$, where $\mathcal P(A)$ is the power set of $A$. If $f$ is onto, for each $b \in B$, $f^{-1}(b)$ is a non-empty subset of $A$. So you can (with the help of the axiom of choice)…

Answer (score 4):

For every $b\in B$, there is at least one $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Choose one, and let $g(b)=a$. Do this for every element in $B$, and $g$ will become a one-to-one function.

This does require the so-called *axiom of choice*, since what you're doing here is exactly constructing a choice function on the set $\{f^{-1}(b)\mid b\in B\}$.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the axiom of choice; in my opinion, the fact that it is required for this construction is the strongest argument in favor of accepting the axiom (despite the baggage that comes with it), because "of course" we should be able to define $g$ in this way.

Comment: @Bungo The axiom of choice is clearly true, the well-ordering principle is clearly false, and who can say about Zorn's lemma?